# Non blocking wait for child processes to exit

Tags: c, wait, fork

I have a program in C that launches 100 child processes with `fork()` and then waits for them to fininsh using a wait in a loop. I would like to wait a maximum amount of time for them all to finish, so the parent process doesn't stay blocked if one of them is, and if that time is over, kill the unfinished ones.

Which would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set an alarm for the desired time.  If the alarm fires, kill whichever of the list of children you original had have not yet died, and send them appropriate 'go away' signals.

I recommend sending SIGTERM or SIGHUP first; then collect the bodies.  If there are any left over after another short delay, then send the SIGKILL signal.  If you get too dramatic (SIGKILL) too quickly, the programs do not get an opportunity to clean up any mess they've made.

Answer (score 0):

The child processes need to signal that they are finished to the main process in some way (you can have them pass a message back to the main process, have them create a file stating that they are finished, or whatever other way is easiest for you). Once that mechanism is in place, have the main process check for the signal that the processes have finished, if it has received them all then continue on, otherwise wait some amount of time before checking again. In this loop add a check to see if you max timeout has been reached, and if so then continue.